# Check a text box based on its Text value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following checkbox in an asp page-

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'/>
```

I want to set the `Checked` value to either `true` or `false` determined on the

`Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'` value.

So if - `'<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'` is equal to `1` then `Checked="True"`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: is this checkbox inside a gridview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add this to your checkbox

```
Checked='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString().Equals("1") %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Equals("1")` in `Checked` property.

```
Checked='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString().Equals("1") %>'
```

Comment: He wants to set Checked value based on value set to Text

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" 
              runat="server" 
              Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString().Equals("1") %>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() == "1" %>'/>
```